# How to open file in another folder in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have the directory hierarchy below: module2 imports module1 which uses file1. When I run module2 a "file not found" error occurs. How to open files in these situations correctly?

**EDIT**: This project will be used by different people so it should work on other machines

```
    \dir1
        -file1.txt
        -module1.py
    \dir2
        -module2.py
```

Comment: How do you use `file1.txt` from `module1.py`?

Comment: @norok2, actually file1.txt is a csv file and I read it via Pandas in module1.py.

Comment: Could you report the code that you use? Perhaps this can be of help.

Comment: @norok2, there is a line in module1.py ```DF = pd.read_csv('coordinates.csv', index_col=0, keep_default_na=False)``` And then I import this module in module2.

Comment: How do you plan to distribute your software? `pip` or just copying files manually or else?

Comment: @norok2, nothing special, just GitHub and simple archive sending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few relatively simple options for you:

1. do not use multiple modules
2. have the modules in the same directory
3. open the file specifying the whole path

---

I guess options 1 and 2 do not require further explanation. As for option 3, what you can do is:

- extract the path where `module1.py` is at the moment of execution
- use that path when opening the support file

In code, this could read (in `module1.py`):

```
import os


dirpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
filepath = os.path.join(dirpath, 'file1.txt')
open(filepath)  # or whatever you use to open the file
```

Answer (score 0):

You need either make a folder for your Python modules and add that directory to your python PATH or add the directory of all your modules to your PATH.

Alternatively, you need to copy all of your modules from different directories (e.g. \dir2) in your source directory (\e.g. \dir1) that you run your python code from. This is the easiest way to do it,  I think.